# Error in UIPath while running a browser automation : System.ArgumentException: No compiled code to run error CS0234:

Tags: c#, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator

---

### Message Box

System.ArgumentException: No compiled code to run
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ProtectedData' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography' (are you missing an assembly reference?) At line 34

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DataProtectionScope' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography' (are you missing an assembly reference?) At line 36

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ProtectedData' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography' (are you missing an assembly reference?) At line 49

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DataProtectionScope' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography' (are you missing an assembly reference?) At line 51

at UiPath.Activities.System.Utilities.InvokeCode.CompilerRunner.Compile(String code, Int32 errLineOffset, Boolean generateInMemory)

at UiPath.Activities.System.Utilities.InvokeCode.CompilerRunner..ctor(String code, String className, String methodName, Int32 errLineOffset, Boolean generateInMemory)

at UiPath.Activities.System.Utilities.InvokeCode.CSharpInvoker.GetCompilerRunner(String code, String className, String methodName, Int32 errLineOffset, Boolean inMemory)

at UiPath.Activities.System.Utilities.InvokeCode.NetCodeInvoker.GetCompilerRunner(String userCode, List`1 args, String imps, Boolean inMemory)

at UiPath.Activities.System.Utilities.InvokeCode.NetCodeInvoker.Run(String userCode, List`1 inArgs, IEnumerable`1 imps, Object[] args)

at UiPath.Core.Activities.InvokeCode.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)

at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Answer (score 0):

As per the error **"System.Security.Cryptography"** is missing in UIPath reference so import the system package. then restart the UIpath.
[image]